# Make a Property Code Snippet in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, properties, code-snippets

I got tired to write boiler plate properties code such as:

```
public string Name
{
     get { return this.name; }
     set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
}
```

So I decided to make a code snippet in Visual Studio to automate the process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>MVVM Property</Title>
      <Shortcut>propm</Shortcut>
      <Author>MFeinstein</Author>
      <Description>Adds a Property that calls PRISM no Notify any changes</Description>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>type</ID>
          <ToolTip>Replace with the property type</ToolTip>
          <Default>string</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>PropertyName</ID>
          <ToolTip>Replace with the property name</ToolTip>
          <Default>propertyName</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>fieldName</ID>
          <ToolTip>Replace with the field name</ToolTip>
          <Default>fieldName</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[private $type$ $fieldName$;

        public $type$ $PropertyName$
        {
            get { return this.$fieldName$; }
            set { SetProperty(ref $fieldName$, value); }
        }$selected$ $end$]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

the problem is, I wanted to just type the name once, and have it as "name" in the field and as "Name" in the property, with the uppercase. Also, I wanted to automatically group the backing fields in the beginning of the class, just as the good practices recommend.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: In the builtin code snippet `propfull` you need to type both the field name and the property name. If an official code snippet from visual studio doesn't have this, I assume it's imposible.

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment so I will answer.  What about:

`public string Name { get; set; }`

you have no backing variables and the properties can be defined in `<type,name>` pair