# Transform Property Name to lowercase

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I wrote a snippet for Visual Studio 22 with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>ThreadSafeProperty</Title>
      <Shortcut>propts</Shortcut>
      <Description>Creates a thread-safe property with a backing field and a lock object.</Description>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[
public $Type$ $PropertyName$
{
    get
    {
        lock ($PropertyName$_lock)
        {
            return $PropertyName$_field;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        lock ($PropertyName$_lock)
        {
            SetField(ref $PropertyName$_field, value, nameof($PropertyName$));
        }
    }
    private $Type$ $PropertyName$_field;
private object $PropertyName$_lock = new object();
}]]>
      </Code>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>PropertyName</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property Name</ToolTip>
          <Default>MyProperty</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Type</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property Type</ToolTip>
          <Default>int</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I want `$PropertyName$_lock` and `$PropertyName$_field` to be written in lowercase, but i can't find a solution.

I found tutorials and explanations for Visual Studio Code, but these are not working in VS22.

Comment: I'd be happy to be proven wrong, but, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28073122/87698), this is not yet supported.

Comment: that is dumb :(